# No tab selected when i launch the application

Tags: android

I have one activity, with five tabs. When I launch the application by default first tab (with 0 index) is selected.

I want it should work like when I launch the application, none from the five tabs should be selected. when I click on particular tab then it should show UI according to the selected tab.

Comment: If none of the tabs is selected, what do you expect it to show?

Comment: Could you provide detail about how you are creating your tabs? Is it on the action bar?
SDK level?
If no tabs, then what screen are you expecting?

Comment: just i want that when i click then it tab select unless user will shown all five tab but not selected with one of tha tab.

Answer (score 0):

Make the initialization routine select one of the tabs.